# Hive. Does ALTER TABLE tablename CHANGE name1 name2 newdatatype; Remove the underline data for name1?

Tags: hive, hiveql

This may differ from the explanation for some online tutorial. That I found after I run ALTER TABLE tablename CHANGE name1 name2 newdatatype; The underline data is removed? Can someone help understand if this command will wipe out the data rather than just rename the column?

Comment: If the column becomes NULL, then probably the datatype is not compatible with data in the file and it cannot be casted to the newdatatype

Comment: Find the hdfs path of your table and try `hdfs dfs -ls your_path` to see if files are still there. If not, something else removed your data. But definitely not Hive.

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation : 
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-RulesforColumnNames

> The column change command will only modify Hive's metadata, and will
>   not modify data. Users should make sure the actual data layout of the
>   table/partition conforms with the metadata definition.

I don't think altering the column name or datatype would have removed the data, there might be some other process which is wiping the data or may be some parallel user.

Comment: I understand the same way. but I do see this remove all data after run, but this maybe the actual hive implementation from our company configuration. THanks, I will get some more clarification.